# Get information from columns text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have this file:
No  TMNo    EnNo    Name            GMNo    Mode    DateTime
1   1   1                           1   1   09/12/2006 11:09:58
2   1   2                           1   2   09/12/2006 11:09:59
3   1   65535                           1   3   09/12/2006 11:10:00
59949   1   20                          1   20  09/13/2006 03:49:06
59950   1   24                          1   21  09/13/2006 03:49:07

I need to get the information from each column.
No-> has a maximun of 5 digits
EnNo->has a maximun of 5digits
The rest of the columns can go up to 2 digits

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a "please write my code for me" site. What have you tried so far to do this yourself? Please post the code you've written and explain how it's not working the way you'd expect, and someone here can probably help you figure out how to fix it. The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more information about the types of questions that should be asked here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is conceptually how you might want to do that.

```
Dim inFile As StreamReader = File.OpenText("filename.txt")
Dim fields() As String
Do While (inFile.Peek <> -1)
    ' read the fields from the current line in the file
    ' split each line by a space according to your text file
    fields = inFile.ReadLine.Split(" ")
    ' do something with each element in fields
Loop
```

Comment: @DavidCastillo Welcome to SO! Take some time to read the [FAQ]. If this answered your question please mark as answered. Thanks!